# How to automatically close command prompt window after Ant file completes

Tags: batch-file, ant

Currently I have a batch file that is designed to stop my Docker container, build with Ant and then restart the container. It is currently in this form.

```
docker stop <container>
docker rm <container>
docker rmi <image>
start /wait ant -f backend\build.xml 
start /wait ant -f frontend\build.xml
docker build -t <image> .
docker run -d -p <ports> --name <container> <image>
```

The problem with this is that when the lines that call Ant run, they do not automatically close the resulting command prompt after the build script finishes. I have to enter 'exit' first. If I don't use 'start /wait' only the first build file runs and nothing will after it.

I've tried add '& exit' with no luck.

Is there anything I can do to just have it continue with out me typing and entering 'exit'?

Comment: Jesse, IMO if you don't know what type of file `ant` is, you should not be running it. The first thing you should learn when using a batch file, is to use double quoted filenames with their fully qualified absolute path and extension. e.g. ```"%ProgramFiles%\Docker\Docker\resources\docker.exe"``` and ```"S:\ome\Directory\bin\ant.bat"``` You only write the script once, so there's no real need to shorthand in order to save typing time. Once you had realised that `ant` was a batch file itself, i.e `ant.bat`, your web searches would have been significantly more focused and fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

Switching 'start /wait' to 'call' did the trick